# Knex's OrderBy in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, knex.js

I'm trying to learn how to implement advance Typescript types

In `knex.js`, one implementation of `orderBy` is an array of the following

```
{ column: string, order: "asc" | "desc" }
```

I wanted to build a typescript type

```
type OrderBy<T> = {
  column: K in keyof T;
  order?: "asc" | "desc";
}
```

Thus if T was `{ "propA": true, "propB": 1 }`, it would intellisense that `column` should be `"propA"` or `"propB"` and order is `"asc"` or `"desc"`.

Unfortunately, its not working. I tried using existing implementations but either they weren't specific enough or I didn't understand how it worked.

**How would I go about implementing this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the keys in your generic T, you need to do just `keyof T`, and your code will look like this:

```js
interface Column { "propA": true, "propB": 1 }

type OrderBy<T> = {
  column: keyof T;
  order?: "asc" | "desc";
}

// Since knex's OrderBy is an array, your code could be like
const knex: Array<OrderBy<Column>> = [{ column: "propA", order: "asc"  }]
```

You can see this code in the TS playground https://tsplay.dev/lm0Lam